# NHibernate generates update statement for all columns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Does NHibernate always generate update for all columns?

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
}

Person p = Session.Load(1);
p.Name = "New Name";

Session.Flush();//Update for all columns, but I change only Name
```

Is it normal behavior for NHibernate or my mistake? I use Fluent NHibernate and AutoMapping.

Comment: Andy, if some of your other questions have known a solution from other's answer, please accept them so that it may help others who shall have the same question as yours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the default behavior, but you can make NH update modified columns only by adding `dynamic-update="true"` to your `<class>` mapping.

Comment: +1 For mentionning `dynamic-update` in `<class>` mapping. I had forgotten about that since I last used NHibernate. =)

Comment: @Mauricio ¿es una competencia a ver quién se rasca más? Mirá que tengo años de experiencia... ;-)

Comment: jajaja es una adicción esta porquería!! :-)

Answer (score -2):

NHibernate always updates all mapped columns. This should be no trouble if the other columns didn't change, since on update the data has been previously pumped from the underlying datastore, so basically, it only reset the column values to their own orginal values. No problem about it.

If you want to override this behaviour, you need to implement the **[IInterceptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHibernate_IInterceptor.aspx)** interface.

Comment: What is the difference between "That is the default behaviour [...]" and "NHibernate always update all mapped columns [...]". These two sentences are the same to me. So, no downvote are deserved here. Plus, this `dynamic-update` could be performed by implementing the `IInterceptor` interface. So, this is not wrong at all in my opinion. Although my answer might not say about `dynamic-update`, which I humbly admit is a more elegant approach, the downvote is undeserved.

Comment: The former phrase implies you can change the behavior easily (just changing the default `false` to `true`), while the latter implies you can't, or that you need to work a lot to make it do something different. I have no idea how to do it with an IInterceptor, but being a mapping option that is not needed. I only downvoted because the answer was misleading, don't take it personally :-)

Comment: "This should be no trouble if the other columns didn't change..." - actually it is a big problem if the user doing the updating only has UPDATE privileges on certain columns in the table, as in my case.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: Actually, this is very constraint-full to be able to update only a few columns. The application should be able to update everything it needs, so I privilege application accounts over user accounts when connecting to the database. Besides, your situation being what it is, I agree it is a big problem, and I today better agree with you all that Diego's answer is best and is the way to go. =)

Comment: We switch to dynamicUpdate because updating all columns and updating only few columns modified, is not the same. Sql server try to update all indexes of the table, causing slow performance and possible deadlock in some tables.